# Get variable, which is on database stored php

Tags: php, regex

I have a big problem to me. I would like to take a variable which is in database.

Below is my database record:

text1/{{{ $variable }}}/text2

I have define this variable on my php code and i would like to take value from this variable which is:

```
$variable = "more_id";
```

I take this query in my application, I change `{{{ $variable }}}` by preg_replace like below:

```
$input = $pob2['krok_1'];
$res = preg_replace( "/{{{(.+?)}}}/","(\\1) ", $input);
```

var_dump returns me:
`text1/( $variable ) /text2`

but I need `text1/( more_id ) /text2`

Do you have any suggest, how I can do this ?

Przemek

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
$$variable
```

It will use string `more_id` as a `$more_id` variable, so:

```
$more_id  = 'foo';
$variable = 'more_id';

echo $$variable; // output: foo
```